# Choosing out of multiple correct parsers on a single input

Tags: haskell, parsec

I would like to know the best way of parsing an input where multiple parsers can succeed. I have outlined my first failed attempt and an inelegant solution which I hope can be made more idiomatic.

For instance I would like to lex "the", "quick" and "fox" from the following sentence into their own data constructors:

```
"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".
```

So given the following type constructors:

```
data InterestingWord = Quick | The | Fox deriving Show
data Snippet = Word InterestingWord | Rest String deriving Show
```

I would like the output of the parse to be:

```
[Word The,
 Rest " ", Word Quick,
 Rest " brown ", Word Fox,
 Rest " jumped over ", Word The,
 Rest " lazy dog"]
```

Here are the two solutions:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Ord    
import Data.List

data InterestingWord = Quick | The | Fox deriving Show
data Snippet = Word InterestingWord | Rest String deriving Show

testCase = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
-- Expected output:
-- [Word The,
--  Rest " ", Word Quick,
--  Rest " brown ", Word Fox,
--  Rest " jumped over ", Word The,
--  Rest " lazy dog"]

toString Quick = "quick"
toString The = "the"
toString Fox = "fox"

-- First attempt

-- Return characters upto the intended word along
-- with the word itself
upto word = do
  pre <- manyTill anyChar $ lookAhead $ string (toString word)
  word' <- try $ string (toString word)
  return [Rest pre, Word word]

-- Parsers for the interesting words
parsers = [upto Quick,
           upto The, 
           upto Fox]

-- Try each parser and return its results with the 
-- rest of the input.
-- An incorrect result is produced because "choice"
-- picks the first successful parse result.
wordParser = do
  snippets <- many $ try $ choice parsers
  leftOver <- many anyChar
  return $ concat $ snippets ++ [[Rest leftOver]]

-- [Rest "the ",Word Quick,Rest " brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"]        
test1 = parseTest wordParser testCase

-- Correct

-- In addition to the characters leading upto the 
-- word and the word, the position is also returned
upto' word = do
  result <- upto word
  pos <- getPosition
  return (pos, result)

-- The new parsers         
parsers' = [upto' Quick,
            upto' The, 
            upto' Fox]

-- Try each of the given parsers and 
-- possibly returning the results and
-- the parser but don't consume
-- input.
tryAll = mapM (\p -> do
                 r <- optionMaybe $ try (lookAhead p)
                 case r of
                   Just result -> return $ Just (p, result)
                   Nothing -> return $ Nothing
              )

-- Pick the parser that has consumed the least.             
firstSuccess ps = do
  successes <- tryAll ps >>= return . catMaybes
  if not (null successes) then
      return $ Just (fst $ head (sortBy (comparing (\(_,(pos,_)) -> pos)) successes))
  else return $ Nothing

-- Return the parse results for the parser that 
-- has consumed the least
wordParser' = do
  parser <- firstSuccess parsers'
  case parser of
    Just p -> do
      (_,snippet) <- p
      return snippet
    Nothing -> parserZero

-- Returns the right result
test2 = parseTest (many wordParser' >>= return . concat) testCase
```

The first attempt "test1" does not produce the desired output because "choice" returns the first parser that succeeds when what I really want is the first parser that succeeds while consuming the least characters. This is what I try next by holding onto the source position of once input has been parsed and using the parser with the lowest source position.

This case seems common enough that I feel I'm missing some obvious combinator incantation. Can anyone offer better suggestions?

Thanks!

-deech

Comment: As a general point - I wouldn't rush to use Parsec for NLP parsing, it's really a tool for parsing programming languages and structured text formats. The Haskell NLP book in progress seems to use the Prelude's `words` and list functions directly - http://nlpwp.org/book/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a particularly common need, but here's an implementation:

```
import Control.Monad
import "parsec3" Text.Parsec
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

longestParse :: [Parsec String () a] -> Parsec String () a
longestParse parsers = do
  allParses <- sequence [lookAhead $ optionMaybe $ try $ 
    liftM2 (,) parse getPosition | parse <- parsers]
  -- allParses :: [Maybe (a, SourcePos)]
  (bestParse, bestPos) <- case catMaybes allParses of
    [] -> fail "No valid parse" -- maybe we can do something better?
    successfulParses -> return $ minimumBy (comparing snd) successfulParses
  setPosition bestPos
  return bestParse
```

Comment: Interesting that this isn't a common use-case and given your answer I guess wasn't too far off.  I really like how you used list comprehension to filter out the successful parses. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to repeatedly parse up to the first interesting word you see.  At the moment, you are parsing up to each interesting word and checking to see which interesting word you found is closer.

My suggestion is to define a parser that checks to see if you currently are at an interesting word (only one of the choices can succeed, so there is no need to do anything fancier than a simple choice).  Then you move forward until the first parser succeeds, which happens when you run into any interesting word.  This gives you the first interesting word because you know nothing before it contained any interesting word.

Yes, this doesn't answer the question of determining which parser match is shortest.  This sidesteps that question by giving a solution to your actual problem that doesn't care which parser match is the shortest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I have multiple parsers that can succeed. Parsec has the "try (...) <|> (...) ..." idiom but, like "choice" it only picks the first one that succeeds. I need to know of the parsers that succeeded which one consumed the least input.